# Jenkins pipeline groovy to upload to WebLogic

Tags: jenkins, groovy, weblogic-10.x

I want to deployto WebLogic using groovy code inside Jenkins job pipeline.

Has anyone ever used a groovy code inside Jenkins job pipeline to deploy to WebLogic application? WebLogic version is 10.x.

I know how to do it with freestyle job and it works via plugin, but when I click on pipeline syntax, I don't see nothing from this plugin.

I have googled and googled, and nothing actually works or is not the scope of my needs and too complex to understand so I could addapt (using Java etc).

SOLVED: OK so I found a way and a way to make it work. Basically one can write a python (jython) code which can manage WebLogic with its built-in WLST scripting mechanism.
But to make everything work, one needs to:

1. generate wlfullclient.jar on your WebLogic machine: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13717/jarbuilder.htm#SACLT239

Use the following steps to create a wlfullclient.jar file for a JDK 1.6 client application:

```
Change directories to the server/lib directory.

cd WL_HOME/server/lib

Use the following command to create wlfullclient.jar in the server/lib directory:

java -jar wljarbuilder.jar

You can now copy and bundle the wlfullclient.jar with client applications.

Add the wlfullclient.jar to the client application's classpath.
```

2. in order for this to work from other machine, without installing WebLogic to it, one needs additional .jar files, which can be found on WebLogic machine in some Weblogic folder e.g. C:\bea10\wlserver_10.3....
3. copy dependent .jar files to desired machine, create empty props.txt file and call your python script like this (in the command you will note which .jar files are also needed in classpath -cp). Dweblogic.home is where weblogic.jar is located. Note that if you gonna put those jars in environment classpath variable, you can NOT add a path to folder, since .jar and .zip files need to be targeted directly.

   java -cp C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\wlfullclient.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.cie.comdev_6.4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.cie.config-wls-schema_10.3.6.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.cie.config-wls_7.2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.cie.config_7.2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.cie.wizard_6.1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\com.oracle.core.weblogic.msgcat_1.2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\jython.jar;C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\weblogic.jar -Dprod.props.file=C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic\props.txt -Dbea.home= -Dweblogic.home=C:\Users\icami\Desktop\weblogic weblogic.WLST test.py

Example of a safe test.py, it only retreives state, listen address etc, doesn't change anything, feel free to run it:

```
username = 'weblogic'
 
password = 'weblogic'
 
URL='t3://weblogic.domain.com:7001'
 
connect(username,password,URL)
 
domainRuntime()
 
cd('ServerRuntimes')
 
servers=domainRuntimeService.getServerRuntimes()
 
for server in servers:
 
    serverName=server.getName();
 
print '**************************************************\n'
 
print '##############    ', serverName,    '###############'
 
print '**************************************************\n'
 
print '##### Server State           #####', server.getState()
 
print '##### Server ListenAddress   #####', server.getListenAddress()
 
print '##### Server ListenPort      #####', server.getListenPort()
 
print '##### Server Health State    #####', server.getHealthState()
```